# PHP - difference of use keyword outside of class and use keyword inside of a class

Tags: php, laravel

Good day guys!

Just want to ask the difference of **use** outise the `class` and **use** inside the `class` ? I have also googled it, but my question doesnt match an answer.

**Example**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       // Some Code
    }
```

Comment: use inside a class is to use traits. use outside is to import namespaces.

Comment: @Augwa what do you mean by that?  can you provide a better explanation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you define a class, it can only have access to other classes within its namespaces. Your controller for instance is defined within the following namespace.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

So to use other classes, you need to import them from their own namespaces so you can access them. e.g.:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
```

If you have javascript ES6 experience, it's a little bit similar to `import`. When you import a package, the default namespace is `/node_modules`. To import your own files, you need to sort of namespace them by giving the file location like

```
import '../containers/index.js'
```

Back to Laravel. Now that you have imported the `ThrottlesLogins`, which is actually a trait, now inside the class you `use` it to expose all of the methods inside.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins; //import
public class AuthController
{
    use ThrottlesLogins; //exposes all the methods inside
    ...

    public function login()
    {
        ...
        //login failed 
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts(); //defined in ThrottlesLogins Trait
    }
}
```

From the example above, you have direct access to `incrementLoginAttempts()`, which is defined the `ThrottlesLogins`.

Comment: Good example :)

Comment: comments.shout_out("absolutely brilliant answer");